# How to execute Dynamic sql with insert statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, dynamic-sql, toad

Below sql command is not working in procedure

```
PROCEDURE P_EMPDETAIL

AS

V_WHERE := 'E.EMP_ID = 123'B

BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE E ' || V_WHERE || ;

END;
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You can't end a string with ||. You must add something after that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there are various issues with your syntax and approach (you shouldn't be using dynamic SQL this way), perhaps you should learn PL/SQL and reference the manuals. The insert statement is also wrong. Below is the correct syntax.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_EMPDETAIL as
V_WHERE varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    V_WHERE := 'E.EMP_ID = 123';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE E (colname) values (1) ' || V_WHERE;
END;
```

Comment: That's still invalid; raises **ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended** as it evaluates to `INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE E (colname) values (1) E.EMP_ID = 123`

Comment: it was pseudo code... the whole procedure is wrong.. not even declared properly. This looks like a homework question, I just got it to at least compile.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not exactly like that (obviously; otherwise, you wouldn't be asking for help).

It is unclear what you want to do because syntax is really strange. If you wanted to **insert** a row into the table, then:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE employees
  2  (
  3     emp_id   NUMBER
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_empdetail (par_emp_id IN NUMBER)
  2  AS
  3     l_str  VARCHAR2 (200);
  4  BEGIN
  5     l_str := 'insert into employees (emp_id) values (:1)';
  6
  7     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str
  8        USING par_emp_id;
  9  END;
 10  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> EXEC p_empdetail(123);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM employees;

    EMP_ID
----------
       123

SQL>
```